# How to find disk usage more than 70% and display largest file in them

Tags: awk, disk-usage

I have a problem, how to find disk usage more than 70%, can be found forwarded by finding the largest file in them, then displaying it?

Please help me with the shell script, thanks for the attention.

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: I have tried a script, but I have not found exactly what I meant, what is needed is only to find the largest file from the filesystem which has xx% utilization.

Can it be combined into the one script? So if there is a fileusage of more than xx% then look for and display the largest file with the head -10?

Comment: i have tried with script: $ df -Ph | awk '+$5>=10 || $1=="Filesystem"' && du -h | sort -nr | head -10 || echo Fail usage is less from 10%

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all the relevant information. Don't spread it around multiple comments as that makes it much harder for people to understand what it is that you want. Make it easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a shell script, but `baobab` is a very useful disk usage analyzer.
[image]

Type `baobab` on command line to start it.

Comment: ok thanks this is similar to zabbix

Answer (score -1):

command1: It display the partition greater than 70 %consumption

```
df -Ph| awk 'NR >1'| sed "s/%//g"| awk 'BEGIN {print "disk space issue exsists"}($(NF-1) > 70) {$(NF-1)=$(NF-1)"%";print $0}'
```

command2 display largest space consumption file of partition whose space consumption is greater than 70

```
for i in `df -Ph| awk 'NR >1'| sed "s/%//g"| awk '($(NF-1) > 70) {$(NF-1)=$(NF-1)"%";print $NF}'`; do  echo $i | awk -v i="$i" 'BEGIN{print "Below is the largestfile exists on partion"i}'; find $i -type f -printf "%s %p\n" 2>/dev/null| sort -k1 -nr | sed -n '1p'; echo "========================================";done
```

Comment: KIndly let me know the reason for downvote

Comment: ok thanks this is very useful